# Computed Observable not updating on selection change

Tags: knockout.js

I've looked at this for a few hours now and can't figure out what's missing. I've tried retooling the computed observable into a pureComputed, but it didn't help. I've looked at adding an ".extend({notify: 'always'});" to the end per [KnockoutJS Forcing A Computed Observable to Re-Compute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372330/knockoutjs-forcing-a-computed-observable-to-re-compute), but didn't help. I made the numStudents an observable, but that didn't help either. Not sure what combination I'm missing. Also made the availableClassSize to have observables in it as well. I set up the Num Students dropdown like this

```
<select data-bind="
    options: $root.availableClassSize,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue: 'value',
    value: numStudents()">
</select>
```

and the computed function is

```
// computed functions
self.totalClassSize = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.assistants(), function (asst) { total += asst.numStudents(); });
    return total;
});
```

Since it's not a writeable/updateable, I didn't think it needed the valueHasMutated() option. I'm out of ideas, and would think that with observables behind the scenes the computed would update when you change the value of the Num Students dropdown. When I add an assistant, it does update the total, but that's for a new row. TIA, Steve

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/cz412oqr/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do to get it to work is change `value: numStudents()">` to `value: numStudents">`. See the "optionsValue" section [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), which explains (emphasis added by me):

> Similar to optionsText, you can also pass an additional parameter
>   called optionsValue to specify **which of the objects’ *properties***
>   should be used to set the value attribute on the  elements
>   that KO generates.

The key point is that you're specifying the *property* you want to have the updated value.

And here is the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cz412oqr/18/).

Comment: I think we've probably all been there at one point or another!

Comment: I was thinking about this more at lunch, and I think what happened is when I added totals, it dawned on me that numStudents needs to be observable, and started adding () everywhere..